# Getting date information about a facebook access token

Tags: javascript, json, http, facebook-graph-api

In the facebook graph api is there a way to see WHEN the access token was created? I would like to get some information about when a user actually logged and gave their permissions. I have been looking everywhere and can't find any real information on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `debug_token` endpoint is what you're looking for.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/debug_token/

The date the token was created is in the `issued_at` field:

```
debug_token?fields=issued_at&input_token=USER'S_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It should be noted, though, that the token may not have been issued at the same time the user *first* logged in and granted permissions. If you need that, you should store it in your own database when the user first authenticates to your system.